# can't access to a spring boot API based in remote docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, remote-access, remote-server

I'm trying to get a connection to a Spring Boot application containerized in a old docker:

My docker version is 1.12.2
Spring Boot 2.5.1

here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
ADD manager.jar manager.jar
EXPOSE 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev","-jar","manager.jar"]
```

I've build the image inside docker with this simple command:

```
 docker build -t manager .
```

and then run the container:

```
docker run -p 8443:8443 -t manager manager
```

But when I'm trying to have a connection by typing the adress:

```
https://SERVERNAME:8443
```

...timeout.

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Can you post the docker logs? Or check whether the spring boot app is listening to 8443?

Comment: Docker options like `-p` need to come _before_ the image name.  Otherwise it gets interpreted as the command to run, and with that entrypoint setup, you should see the options unprocessed as arguments to your `main` function.

Comment: Thanks for your return, I've change the running command (edit my first post) but same result.

Comment: The logs ( "docker logs manager") give my only the starting process of the spring boot api and everything is ok. Here is the last line: "Tomcat started on port(s): 8443 (https) with context path '/manager'"

Comment: I've tried to ping the server ( ping SERVER) and I've an answer but if I try to ping the port ( telnet SERVER 8443 ), I've a failure.... very stranger

Comment: So, not a real solution but I've remove the TLS/SSH settings from the application.properties and changes the dockerfile and everything is ok. It wasn't a Docker problem but a bad server configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like I said in my last post, after remove the TLS properties from the application.properties, everything is solved. It's a server configuration problem.